# Why does Isotope arrange everything in an unchangeable 120pix wide grid?

Tags: jquery-plugins

I'm using Isotope (http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) for a website. As you know Isotope creates a fluid grid of elements that can be filtered, sorted, clicked etc.

It appears that for some reason Isotope orders everything in a grid that in horizontal dimension is multiples of 120px wide, e.g. if I set my elements as 115px wide, then Isotope will ad a small 5px margin to the ride of each element. If my elements are 119px wide, it will ad 1px. If my elements are 121 px wide it will magically ad another full 119px.

Is there a reason for this? How do I change these 120 px to another value?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You probably have [`columnWidth`](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/layout-modes.html#masonry) set to 120, as this is the default value in [the examples](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/elements-partial.html).